# Onepage Checkout Variable Error

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm on Magento Community ver. 1.9.0.1 and I'm stuck fixing a Onepage checkout error.

Users are currently unable to get past entering Billing Information - Clicking the continue button will not advance to the next section. Two errors are showing:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: billing

onepage:389

//billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'http://www.3dpapergreetings.com/directory/json/childRegion/', 'Select State/Province...');
$('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

onepage:619

billing.onSave = function(evt){

It appears to be an issue relating to a billing variable but I have exhausted every possibility I can think of to try. Any assistance in resolving this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering I was able to get it resolved.

An extension (even though disabled) was causing a conflict. Removing that extension, particularly its billing.phtml file, resolved the issue.

Brian